# How to access a Windows PC remotely?

Tags: windows, vnc, remote-access

Here's a situation: my parents live far away from me, and once in a while they call me for computer support. Sometimes as a Skype call from an iPad pointing to the computer screen, and asking me literally "what should I click there?"

It would be much much much easier if I could VNC their computer and access is remotely. However, there are a couple of problems:

1. I am a little rusty with Windows, using OSX or Linux for quite a while, and don't know how to install a VNC server on a PC. What exactly should I ask them to install there?
2. They don't have a permanent IP address. How do I establish a VNC connection with a floating IP address?

Comment: [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.us/) is much easier to use for this kind of situation. I've used it plenty for remote support. It doesn't require any kind of router configuration and you don't even need to know their IP address. I realize this sounds almost like an advertisement, but it's a fairly common thing people use for these situations.

Comment: Yup.  Cisco LogMeIn may be another alternative.  Another option is to have them visit whatismyip.com or ipchicken.com or some other website that shows the IP address.  Dynamic DNS options could also be helpful.  But the problem with just knowing their IP address is that you may still have issues with a firewall blocking your VNC traffic.

Answer (score 0):

For Floating ip address you need to setup DDNS (Dynamic DNS). There are a ton of providers for this that you can setup for free. I use www.dynu.com which also has a windows update client to update the domain host ip when it changes. Some routers provide a baked in list of DDNS services that the router will handle to ip mapping changes.

here are some reviews of others DDNS providers
https://www.keycdn.com/blog/best-free-dns-hosting-providers/

For remote control I would recommend TightVNC or UltraVNC. These are both good options and allows Mom to see what your doing in a shared screen.

Comment: Thanks; I'm now using TeamViewer recommended by n8te, and it works like a charm.